# I need help using CAST to return the month/day only

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

```
SELECT DateAdded,
    CAST(DateAdded AS date USING 'mm:dd') AS MonthDay
FROM Products;
```

Keep getting an error by the "AS".

Comment: Which database you are using

Comment: you can't use 'USING', I'm thinking you're looking for a method like date_format

Comment: SELECT date_format(DateAdded, '%m:%d') AS MonthDay

Comment: SELECT DateAdded,
 CAST(DateAdded AS date) AS Date,
 CAST(DateAdded AS time) AS Time,
 CAST(DateAdded AS date USING 'mm:dd') AS MonthDay
FROM Products;

But I'm getting this error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: Yeah, what we're wanting to know is which flavor of SQL are you using?  MySQL, postgreSQL, hsqldb, Oracle?

Comment: Sorry, VERY new to this!  I'm using MSSQL

Comment: Problem is, I have to use CAST, not CONVERT.

Comment: sounds like an opportunity for you to learn how CAST and CONVERT are different, and the syntax for each. you can make the necessary changes based on what you learn.

Comment: yeah, I understand how to do it using CONVERT, but I just can't figure it would using CAST.  I've tried everything I can think of.

Comment: @Brandi - Only by using `cast` function you cannot do this in `MSSQL`

Comment: Thanks.  It's a school question and the only one I've had such a hard time figuring out that I decided to actually post on here.  There are several typos in other parts of the assignment; I'm wondering if this is supposed to say CONVERT.  I'm just going to do it that way and see what the teacher says.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Month` and `Day` function to extract `month` and `day` from date type. Try this.

```
SELECT DateAdded,      
       Convert(varchar(2),month(DateAdded))+':'+
                Convert(varchar(2),Day(DateAdded)) As MonthDay
FROM Products;
```

or Use `101` style in `convert` and replace the `/` with `:`

```
SELECT DateAdded,      
       Replace(Left(Convert(varchar(20),DateAdded,101),4),'/',':') As MonthDay
FROM Products;
```

Or `Datepart`

```
SELECT DateAdded,      
       Convert(varchar(2),Datepart(Month,DateAdded))+':'+
                Convert(varchar(2),Datepart(Day,DateAdded)) As MonthDay
FROM Products;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution using cast

```
SELECT 
    DateAdded, 
    CAST(DateAdded AS date) AS Date, 
    CAST(DateAdded AS time) AS Time, 
    right('0' + cast(month(DateAdded) as varchar(2)),2) + ':' 
        + right('0' + cast(day(DateAdded) as varchar(2)),2) AS MonthDay 
FROM Products
```